# tmux + fish shell; conf being sourced twice

Tags: tmux, fish

When I start `tmux`, my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` seems to be sourced *again*. This means any `set PATH foo $PATH` statements in my `config` get executed again, which leads to my PATH variable having duplicate entries in it. This isn't drastic, but it is annoying to ECHO path. when it is so long

How can I prevent this problem?

EDIT: the only fish related entires in my tmux file are

`#fix vim
 set -g default-shell $SHELL
 set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l ${SHELL}"
 set -g default-command 'reattach-to-user-namespace $SHELL --login'`

Comment: You should be using the `fish_user_paths` variable ("an array of directories that are prepended to PATH") to add custom paths to your PATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *~/.config/fish/config.fish* config file is read by every new fish instance. There are several ways to achieve what you're asking. One option is to always set `PATH` from scratch. That is, don't modify the existing path by appending or prepending to it but instead set it to exactly what you want for a given machine. Something along the lines of

```
set -gx PATH $HOME/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin/ /bin
test -d /opt/X11/bin
and set PATH $PATH /opt/X11/bin
```

Another option is to add directories only if they aren't already in the path:

```
contains /usr/local/bin $PATH
or set PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH
```

Or only do the modification if not inside a tmux session:

```
if not set -q TMUX
    set PATH /argle/bargle $PATH
end
```